# I have main activity with 7 buttons

Tags: android, button, android-activity

Each button open a different activity i already created 8 classes include MainActivity,

it works for 1 button btw but i use the same code for another button and the app just shutdown.

Help i'm a begginer .

here is the code for 1 button:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static Button button_lb1, button_lb2, button_lb3, button_cf, button_dp, button_tp, button_cal;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    OnClickButtonListener();
}
public void OnClickButtonListener() {
    button_lb1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_lubri);
    button_lb1.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent("com.silvio.myapplication.SecondActivity");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
    button_lb2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_lubri2);
    button_lb2.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent("com.silvio.myapplication.ThirdActivity");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
}
```

}
Thx for your time !

Comment: Please add the LogCat / stack trace to your question. Did you add your `SecondActivity` to the android manifest ?

Comment: Please Post *Logcat*.

Comment: This code is working but i want to use another button but with the same code

Comment: I will post the 2nd button code

Comment: @SilvioPereira Use *Switch Case*.

Comment: You are setting listener on only 1 button, set listener on all buttons. And call `intent` like this `Intent i = new Intent(YouActivityName.this, Your_New_Activity.class) .. startActivity(i)`

Comment: Also do register your activities in AndroidManifest.xml, If you are using Android Studio, creating activity from the `New` menu will do that automatically

Comment: i dont know how to use that, :( i saw this code on tutorial and i tought if i change the button names and acitivity names would work , :(

Comment: i have my all activities on the xml

Comment: thx for all i will try dat Murtaza

Comment: i add the 2nd button code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code for opening the new activity.

```
public void OnClickButtonListener() {
button_lb1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_lubri);
button_lb1.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MianActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
);
button_lb2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_lubri2);
button_lb2.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MianActivity.this,ThirdActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
);
```

also add your activities in AndroidManifest file as well by using the following code

Inside `<application>` tag of manifest you can add new activity like:

```
<activity android:name=".newActivity"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example: how to use intents (better way):**

```
Intent intent1= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), goToThisClass.class);
                    startActivity(intent1);

                    Intent intent2= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), goToThisClass2.class);
                    startActivity(intent2);
```